# JOOQ forced type code generation

Tags: java, postgresql, type-conversion, jooq

I'm having some problems generating code using forced types (JOOQ 3.3, Postgres 9.3).

Trying to convert sql timestamp to joda DateTime, leads me to compilation errors.

My table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE book
(
  // [...]
  date_published timestamp without time zone,
  // [...]
);
```

and my .xml config:

```xml
// [...]
<customTypes>
  <customType>
   <name>java.sql.Timestamp</name>
   <converter>com.plannow.jooq.converters.DateTimeConverter</converter>
  </customType>         
</customTypes>
<forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
   <name>java.sql.Timestamp</name>
   <expression>.*\.date_.*</expression>
   <types>.*</types>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
// [...]
```

DateTimeConverter class:

```java
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, DateTime>
{

    @Override
    public DateTime from(Timestamp databaseObject)
    {
        return new DateTime(databaseObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Timestamp to(DateTime userObject)
    {
        return new Timestamp(userObject.getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Timestamp> fromType()
    {
        return Timestamp.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DateTime> toType()
    {
        return DateTime.class;
    }
}
```

So, BOOK.DATE_PUBLISHED is being generated like this:

```java
public final org.jooq.TableField<com.plannow.jooq.db.tables.records.BookRecord, java.sql.Timestamp> DATE_PUBLISHED = createField("date_published", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP, this, "", new com.plannow.jooq.converters.DateTimeConverter());
```

which leads to compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from TableField<BookRecord,DateTime> to TableField<BookRecord,Timestamp>.
```

I know i can change type of `DATE_PUBLISHED` to `TableField<BookRecord,DateTime>` and refactor the code,  but i dont want to patch the generated classes manually.

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<name/>` element of your `<customType/>` should refer to the `<U>` type (user type) of your [`Converter<T, U>`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Converter.html), not to the `<T>` type (database type). So if you write this:

```xml
<customTypes>
  <customType>
   <name>java.sql.Timestamp</name>
   <converter>com.plannow.jooq.converters.DateTimeConverter</converter>
  </customType>         
</customTypes>
```

Then you're really just registering a `Converter<Timestamp, Timestamp>`. Try this instead:

```xml
<customTypes>
  <customType>
   <name>org.joda.time.DateTime</name>
   <converter>com.plannow.jooq.converters.DateTimeConverter</converter>
  </customType>         
</customTypes>
```

Note that your converter should also correctly handle `null` values:

```java
@Override
public DateTime from(Timestamp t)     {
    return t == null ? null : new DateTime(t);
}

@Override
public Timestamp to(DateTime u) {
    return u == null ? null : new Timestamp(u.getMillis());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I really dont know how did i miss the` <!-- Specify the fully-qualified class name of your custom type -->` comment. Anyway thanks again

Comment: @user3215799: It happens to the best ;-)