# Casting org.jooq.TableField<Long> to org.jooq.TableField<BigDecimal>

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I was wondering if anybody can help me with casting the table object type from Long to BigDecimal?

In sql, the code is like this:

```
AND   table_nameA.row_name = table_nameB.row_name
```

In jooq is just simple as:

```
and(table_nameA.row_name.eq( table_nameB.row_name))
```

I tried to cast it with

`Select <? extends Record1<BigDecimal>` but I received a `ClassCastException org.jooq.immpl.TableFieldImpl cannot be cast to org.jooq.Select`.

And when I tried to cast it with `(BigDecimal)`, I received a `ClassCastException org.jooq.immpl.TableFieldImpl cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal`.

thanks.

Comment: Why should you really do this casting?

`TableField<BigDecimal> table_nameA.row_name = TableField<Long> table_nameB.row_name` does not looks like sql

Comment: abc.ABC_DEF_PAR_NUMBER data type is in Jooq is defined/generated in BigDecimal and def.DEF_PAR_NUMBER data type in Jooq is defined/generated in Long. I am not allowed.post the real actual sql statement, I can be fired if I do so.

Comment: Why should I really do this casting? Because jooq generated these two in two different data types, I don't know why. An example from the actual sql statement is AND abc.ABC_DEF_PAR_NUMBER  = def.DEF_PAR_NUMBER. in jooq should be just as simple as .and(abc.ABC_DEF_PAR_NUMBER.eq(ef.DEF_PAR_NUMBER)).

Comment: Try to regenerate your schemata with forced jooq type converters 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979524/jooq-forced-type-code-generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to work around this data type mismatch.

#### Data type coercion

If you don't care about the different data types generated by jOOQ for different `NUMBER` / `DECIMAL` / `NUMERIC` precisions and scales, then you can use `Field.coerce()`, which comes in three overloaded flavours:

- [`Field.coerce(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-java.lang.Class-) (coerce the type to a Java class)
- [`Field.coerce(DataType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-org.jooq.DataType-) (coerce the type to a `DataType` (including its data type binding))
- [`Field.coerce(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-org.jooq.Field-) (coerce the type to the `DataType` of another field)

In your case, the latter probably works best:

```java
table_nameA.row_name.eq(table_nameB.row_name.coerce(table_nameA.row_name))
```

Coercion does not affect the generated SQL, it just forces a `Field` reference to be of a certain `DataType`.

#### Raw type casting

The poor man's alternative to coercion might be a raw type cast:

```java
table_nameA.row_name.eq((Field) table_nameB.row_name)
```

This is generally not recommended, but still maybe worth mentioning as a last resort.

#### SQL `CAST()`

You can always cast a `Field` to a specific data type in SQL as well. This is useful if your data types have differing scales and you want the scales to match, e.g. because you want to treat `1.0001 = 1.0` or even `'1' = 1`.

There are again three flavours of `Field.cast()`:

- [`Field.cast(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#cast-java.lang.Class-)
- [`Field.cast(DataType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#cast-org.jooq.DataType-)
- [`Field.cast(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#cast-org.jooq.Field-)

In your case:

```java
table_nameA.row_name.eq(table_nameB.row_name.cast(table_nameA.row_name))
```

This is different from coercing in that the generated SQL will contain a `CAST()` (which might negatively impact performance, of course, as ordinary indexes cannot be used on the `CAST` expression)

The generated SQL will look something like this:

```sql
TABLE_NAMEA.ROW_NAME = CAST(TABLE_NAMEB.ROW_NAME AS BIGINT)
```

#### Generate your code differently

If you believe that either of the generated types (e.g. `Long`) was generated by mistake, you can either:

1. Fix your database schema and add some precision / scale to the column that generated a `BigDecimal` (in Oracle), or make it a `BIGINT` (in other databases)
2. Re-generate your schema with the [data type rewriting feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/) turned on for that column, e.g.

   ```xml
   <forcedType>
     <name>BIGINT</name>
     <expression>(?i:.*?\.TABLE_NAMEB\.ROW_NAME)</expression>
   </forcedType>
   ```