# jooq java.lang.CastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: jooq, vert.x

In a Project I am using jklingsporn vertx-jooq as jooq-CodeGenerator to create vertxified DAOs and POJOS as async.
I have a generated ContractDao.java class

```
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.classic.async.AsyncClassicQueryExecutor;

/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@Generated(value = { "http://www.jooq.org", "jOOQ version:3.10.6" }, comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ")
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class ContractDao extends AbstractAsyncVertxDAO<ContractRecord, jooq.tables.pojos.Contract, Long, Future<List<jooq.tables.pojos.Contract>>, Future<jooq.tables.pojos.Contract>, Future<Integer>, Future<Long>> implements io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.classic.VertxDAO<ContractRecord, jooq.tables.pojos.Contract, Long> {

    /**
     * @param configuration
     *            Used for rendering, so only SQLDialect must be set and must be one
     *            of the MYSQL types or POSTGRES.
     * @param delegate
     *            A configured AsyncSQLClient that is used for query execution
     */
    public ContractDao(Configuration configuration, io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.AsyncSQLClient delegate) {
        super(Contract.CONTRACT, jooq.tables.pojos.Contract.class, new AsyncClassicQueryExecutor<ContractRecord, jooq.tables.pojos.Contract, Long>(configuration, delegate, jooq.tables.pojos.Contract::new, Contract.CONTRACT));
    }
  ....

 }
```

which uses the generated Contract.java pojo class with a BigDecimal field.

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.10.6"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class Contract implements VertxPojo, IContract {

    ...
    private BigDecimal costValue;
    ...

}
```

then in the vert.x Verticle class I have a method fetchContracts:

```
    private void fetchContracts(final Message<Void> msg) {
        contractDao.findAll().setHandler(arContracts -> {
            ...
        });
    }
```

so far it works fine, but if I have a numeric value in the Table Contract field costValue, when I call the fetchContracts method I get an exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I guess there is some kind of a data type mismatch. I have seen, if I understand it correct, that this could be solved with Data type coercion or casting as explained here: [Casting org.jooq.TableField<Long> to org.jooq.TableField<BigDecimal>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834455/casting-org-jooq-tablefieldlong-to-org-jooq-tablefieldbigdecimal)

But in this particular case it is not clear for me where and how the casting should be performed.

I tried something like:

```
    private void fetchContracts(final Message<Void> msg) {
        jooq.tables.Contract.CONTRACT.COST_VALUE.coerce(String.class);
        contractDao.findAll().setHandler(arContracts -> {
            ...
        });
    }
```

But it is not working. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Edited:

I add the stack trace:

```
[ERROR] 2018-08-07 09:42:54,368: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number ( de.bfft.licencemgmt.server.UserVerticle.lambda$100(UserVerticle.java:998)) [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1]  []
[ERROR] 2018-08-07 09:42:54,368: (RECIPIENT_FAILURE,500) java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number ( de.bfft.licencemgmt.client.viewslogic.agreements.AgreementsViewLogic.lambda$6(AgreementsViewLogic.java:61)) [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4]  []
[ERROR] 2018-08-07 09:42:54,368: Failed to handleMessage. address: 1 ( io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:228)) [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4]  []
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractExtension.extend(AbstractExtension.java:77) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.4.jar:8.4.4]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Notification.show(Notification.java:502) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.4.jar:8.4.4]
    at de.bfft.licencemgmt.client.viewslogic.agreements.AgreementsViewLogic.lambda$0(AgreementsViewLogic.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:165) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.fail(FutureImpl.java:97) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at de.bfft.licencemgmt.client.viewslogic.agreements.AgreementsViewLogic.lambda$6(AgreementsViewLogic.java:62) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$convertHandler$1(EventBusImpl.java:349) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:223) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:200) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:533) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) [netty-transport-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
[ERROR] 2018-08-07 09:42:54,383: Unhandled exception ( io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:345)) [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4]  []
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractExtension.extend(AbstractExtension.java:77) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.4.jar:8.4.4]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Notification.show(Notification.java:502) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.4.jar:8.4.4]
    at de.bfft.licencemgmt.client.viewslogic.agreements.AgreementsViewLogic.lambda$0(AgreementsViewLogic.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:165) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.fail(FutureImpl.java:97) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at de.bfft.licencemgmt.client.viewslogic.agreements.AgreementsViewLogic.lambda$6(AgreementsViewLogic.java:62) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$convertHandler$1(EventBusImpl.java:349) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.deliver(HandlerRegistration.java:223) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.handle(HandlerRegistration.java:200) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$deliverToHandler$3(EventBusImpl.java:533) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339) ~[vertx-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) [netty-transport-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.19.Final.jar:4.1.19.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

And the code causing the exception in UserVerticle.java class, the line 998 in the stack trace corresponds to the third line below "log.error(arContracts.cause())":

```
    private void fetchContracts(final Message<Void> msg) {
        contractDao.findAll().setHandler(arContracts -> {
            if (arContracts.failed()) {
                log.error(arContracts.cause());
                msg.fail(500, arContracts.cause().getMessage());
                return;
            }
            final List<Contract> contracts = arContracts.result();

            log.debug("Found {} contracts", contracts.size());
            final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(
                    contracts.stream().map(contract -> contract.toJson()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            msg.reply(jsonArray);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Also, please post the actual code causing the exception. The exception is probably thrown from `...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the conversion of decimal in json. Json converts automatically decimal numbers into strings, but it was expecting a decimal number, which provoked somehow the exception

It turned out, there was an additional CustomVertxGenerator.java class which extends ClassicAsyncVertxGenerator for vert.x-jooq with a method to handle additional types from/into a String during JSON-conversion. And this was new to me.

When the conversion for numeric types from the postgresql db was fixed in the method of the class, the problem was resolved.